# Create new entries for a particular account_id in the same using postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have a table called account(id,account_id,name,status). Already data is present for these columns say:

Table account:

[image: id. account_id. name. status]

I have to first query the account_id with the name as xyz and create new entries for that account_id with name as kjf and lmn and status as fail.

The new table will look like as below after insert

[image]

Can someone help me for writing a query for this? I had tried :

INSERT INTO account (id, account_id, name, status,)
  SELECT uuid_generate_v4(), account_id, 'kjh', 'fail' FROM account;

This shows error as account_is is unique.

Comment: Does `INSERT INTO account(account_id, name, status) VALUES (765, 'kjh', 'fail')` not work? How does it matter what other rows already exist?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned but I have to add entries for that account_id whose name is xyz and then change their name to kjh, like if there would have been 2 entries for xyz (say account_id 765 and account_id 987) now I have to add entries like id = 5, account_id = 987, name = kjh, status=fail. Basically first fetch account_id with name=xyz and add new entries for that, I'm unable to combine the queries.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show the two queries you have (fetching account_id, inserting new values) and how you tried (but failed) to combine them?

Answer (score 0):

With SQL, you can try this:

```
with 
 v1 as (select max(id)+1 as maxid from account),
 v2 as (select account_id as newid from account where name='xyz')
insert into account
 select (select maxid from v1), (select newid from  v2), 'kjh', 'fail';
```